# XML - extracting value from specific node

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

im struggling with extracting value from a specific node in my XML document. Im using w3c.DOM as i have found many tutorials on it but now i cant find any good ones for this task - i had to use XPath for this task instead.

I always know the exact path (and passing it as a string, example: `"Car/Wheels/Wheel[@Index=´x´]/"` ) leading to a node from which i need to extract a value (a string) and return it (im converting the string into doubles and integers in other methods later). Variable myDoc is Document myDoc.

How do i get this value?

```
private String xPathValue(String path){

XPath myPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr =  xpath.compile(path);  
String result = (String)expr.evaluate(myDoc);  

return result;
}
```

This however doesnt work and i dont want to create any NodeList since i know the exact paths. Im looking for something that works like `Node.getTextContent();`

Comment: Where is your XML document? Depending on your XPath expression (what are you actually selecting) you would deal with the results differently (in different objects such as `NodeList`, `Node`, `String`. Show your actual code and your XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options

1) Alter you xPath to return the value of the node instead of the node itself

Using expression: `Car/Wheels/Wheel[@Index=´x´]/text()`

```
private String xPathValue(String path) {
    XPath myPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr =  xpath.compile(path);  
    String result = (String)expr.evaluate(myDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);  

    return result;
}
```

---

2) Use the same xpath query but return a node type

Using expression: `Car/Wheels/Wheel[@Index=´x´]`

```
private String xPathValue(String path) {
    XPath myPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr =  xpath.compile(path);  
    Node result = (Node)expr.evaluate(myDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);  

    return result.getTextContent();
}
```

Comment: Whow, this solution actually works, thanks a lot man. Thats a nice easy trick.